# how to check whether xml file is valid

Tags: xml

I'm learning xml. 
I create small xml files and dfd files.
This is xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"?>
<!DOCTYPE software SYSTEM "software.dtd"
[
<!ATTLIST title ttl CDATA "no name">
<!ATTLIST license lcs CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
<software>
<application>
    <suite>
        <app>
            <title ttl="MOffice">Microsoft Office</title>
            <developer>Microsoft</developer>
            <os>Microsoft Windows</os>
            <license>Trialware</license>
        </app>
        <app>
            <title>iWork</title>
            <developer>Apple</developer>
            <os>Mac OS</os>
            <license>Proprietary</license>
        </app>
        <app>
            <title ttl="Office">Open Office</title>
            <developer>StarOffice,OpenOffice.org,Apache OpenOffice</developer>
            <os>Linux, Mac OS, Microsoft Windows</os>
            <license>LGPL,Apache License</license>
        </app>
    </suite>
</application>  
</software>
```

And this is dfd file

```
<!ELEMENT software(application)>
<!ELEMENT application(suite) >
<!ELEMENT suite(app*)>
<!ELEMENT app(title,developer,os,license)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT developer(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT os(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT license(#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST os osx CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

It should be incorred xml file because there is no attributes `osx` and `lcs` in `os` and `license` elements. But Internet Explorer opens it normal. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most XML parsers, including the one in Internet Explorer, only check XML for well-formedness - to ensure that the XML structure is correct.

In order to validate against a DTD or [XML Schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema), you need to use a [validating parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_validation).

The exact process of how to use such a parser for validation depends on the parser and programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Python example for the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15419497/11154841) - the `...` are placeholders, an xsd file must be one full abstract structure of what has to be in the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema ...>
   <xs:complexType name="xyz">
...
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="abc">
...
   </xs:complexType>
...
```

Just get an xsd file from wherever, there must be one to validate against.

Python file: "validate.py"

```py
import xmlschema

my_xml = '/path/to/file.xml'
some_xsd_validation_schema = '/path/to/file.xsd'

xmlschema.validate(my_xml, some_xsd_validation_schema)
```

Then run `python validate`